# From how many nodes do you need dedicated master nodes

Tags: elasticsearch

A question. Is there any recommandation from how many nodes that you need to use dedicated master nodes in a elasticsearch cluster?

My setup:

- 4 nodes: for non critical data (32GB ram) each. Can be the master node 3
- 3 nodes: for critial data (16GB ram) each.

Does the master nodes need the same memory requirement as the data nodes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At a time you can have only [one master node](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-discovery-zen.html#_cluster_state_updates), but for availability you should have more than one master elegible by setting [**node.master**](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-node.html#master-node)

The master node is the only node in a cluster that can make changes to the cluster state. This mean that if your master node is rebooted or down then you will not be able to make any changes to your cluster.

Well at some point it is a bit hard to what is right or best practice because it always depends on many parameters.

With your setup i would better go with 3 nodes and up to [64 GB of memory](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/heap-sizing.html#compressed_oops) per each node, other wise you are loosing some hits on communication between your 7 servers while they are not utilizing 100% of resources. Then all [3 nodes](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/1.x/_important_configuration_changes.html) must be able to become master and set

```
discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes: 2
```

This parameter is a bit important to avoid **brain split** when each node could become a master.

For you critical data you must use [1 replica](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_how_primary_and_replica_shards_interact.html) to prevent lose of data.

Other option would be to make master only nodes and data only nodes.

So at some point minimum master nodes should be always 3 this will allow you to upgrade without downtime and make sure that you have always on setup.

Comment: Now I have 6 node and 3 nodes are data and can be master. So my question is is this a bad pratice. And the second question does the master node have the same memory requirements as the data nodes.

Comment: @GeoffreySamper Can you please update question with your setup? (I want to know how much memory each node has)